# Case columns to one row in oralce

Tags: oracle

```
  SELECT 
         t.LAST_NAME,

         MAX (
            CASE
               WHEN TSI.SERVICE = 1 THEN 'Short Course – Facilitation only'
            END)
            Col1,
         MAX (CASE WHEN TSI.UNIT = 1 THEN 'Dint' END) rate1,
         MAX (
            CASE
               WHEN TSI.SERVICE = 2 THEN 'Short Course – Assessment only'
            END)
            Col2,
         MAX (CASE WHEN TSI.UNIT = 3 THEN 'Dillnt' END) rate3,
         MAX (
            CASE WHEN TSI.SERVICE = 3 THEN 'Short Course – Assessment ' END)
            Col3


    FROM LMS$TRAINERS T
         JOIN
         trainer_service_info TSI
            ON     T.trainer_id = TSI.trainer_id
               AND COMPANY_ID = :P0_COMPANY_ID
               AND status = 'A'
GROUP BY t.TRAINER_ID,
         t.FIRST_NAME,
         t.LAST_NAME,
         t.ID_NUM,
         t.DATE_OF_BIRTH,
         t.CLOCK_NO,
         t.CONTACT_NO,
         TSI.Service,
         TSI.UNIT,
         TSI.RATE,
         t.language,
         t.rating,
         t.ID_TYPE,
         t.LMS_SPECIALITY_AREA,
         t.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
         t.STATUS_REASON,
         t.DEFAULT_BRANC_ID
```

Above code produces - Trimmed down for easier presentation

```
Name   Col1                Rate1     Col2               Rate3
Maruma Facilitation only    Dint                
Maruma                               Assessment only    Dillnt
```

Would like it to produce

```
Name   Col1                Rate1     Col2               Rate3   
Maruma Facilitation only    Dint    Assessment only     Dillnt
```

Comment: Please post some sample data. That would be much easier for us to help you.

Comment: Not sure how to add data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your group by is a huge list of columns:

```
     t.TRAINER_ID,
     t.FIRST_NAME,
     t.LAST_NAME,
     t.ID_NUM,
     t.DATE_OF_BIRTH,
     t.CLOCK_NO,
     t.CONTACT_NO,
     TSI.Service,
     TSI.UNIT,
     TSI.RATE,
     t.language,
     t.rating,
     t.ID_TYPE,
     t.LMS_SPECIALITY_AREA,
     t.EMAIL_ADDRESS,
     t.STATUS_REASON,
     t.DEFAULT_BRANC_ID
```

It doesnt need to be, and is causing this "issue". Change your GROUP BY so that you're just grouping on `t.LAST_NAME` (the only member of your select list that is NOT contained in an aggregate expression)

Otherwise there'll be some other variation in the other values you're grouping by where some cartesian product exists

Caution: this implies that you *could* end up losing or mixing data - there are TWO rows currently that have the same last name but some other detail is different, like maybe first name. The MAX() expressions will not try and keep data from the same row. This means if you have e.g. two people, Sarah Maruma who is 38 and living in Afghanistan and John Maruma who is 19 and living in Zimbabwe you'll end up with a row of mixed values:

Maruma, 38, Zimbabwe

If this is OK, then crack on. If this is NOT OK, then put every column currently in your group by, into your select list too, and look at the results. Find out where the variation is occurring and decide what you want to do about it

Typically you should end up with a query where all the columns in the GROUP BY are also listed in the SELECT (not in any aggregate function)

Comment: The query works with just name in group by - but I have way more columns and with all them in it and group by its creating 2 rows

Comment: I think that's what I said?! As I advised: that list of columns in your group by, put them in the select list also.. That way you'll see what is causing the data to split into two rows! Some columns will be same, others will be different - it's the different ones that is causing the split. Like I said in my example, if you have 2 people with same last name but different first name, the group by on first name will cause the data to split. By saying GROUP BY (20 columns) you're telling oracle you only want unique combinations of all 20 columns. Think again about John Maruma/Sarah Maruma example

Comment: ps; the edit you suggested for my answer isn't to SO guidelines and I rejected it. For more info google "when should i edit an answer on stackoverflow" - editing to talk to the author is basically a no-no; use comments for that